# How can i assign a sequence of random string values to a variable? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random
for x in range (10):
    print (random.choice('GACT'), end=random.choice('GACT'))
```

So I want the output of this code into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> x = ''.join([random.choice('GACT') for i in range(10)])
>>> x
'CGGTGCCCTG'
```

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for?